# How to handle Oauth and non-oauth Authorization using spring security in spring boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

In our application which is a spring 5 application, we have both Oauth and Non-Oauth authentication flow, either of the authentication flow can be using a setting.

For oauth we are using an internal authorization server and getting jwt access token.

for non-oauth we are using same internal authorization server's different endpoint which takes username and password and returns a token which is not a jwt token.

So for authorization we are using two different flows where each flow uses different endpoint to validate the token.

now we are upgrading to spring boot 3 and spring webflux, so we are planning to use spring security for protecting the endpoints.

I have explored about the Oauth using spring security and resource server but it handle only Oauth case.

im following https://medium.com/geekculture/jwt-authentication-with-oauth2-resource-server-and-an-external-authorization-server-2b8fd1524fc8 article to understand about the oauth flow.

My doubt is how to handle both Oauth and non-oauth authorization using spring security in spring boot 3 and spring webflux?

Comment: How is the second type of token validated by API endpoints? Why isn't it "OAuth2"?

Comment: its a normal base64 encoded token, but not a jwt token

Comment: this answers none of my two questions.

Comment: ooh my bad,  we dont have access to that system so we dont have idea how the second token is validated, we just get user details as response.

Comment: Why isn't it "OAuth2" -> it was the old way of handling authorization and some people still uses it so we are supporting both oauth and old way

Comment: OAuth2 tokens are not necessarily JWTs. It is legit for an OAuth2 resource-server to introspect an access-token (which is compatible with opaque tokens). As you seem to have an endpoint returning user-info from opaque tokens, you can use it as introspection endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from comments, your legacy system seems quite easy to integrate in an OAuth2 solution using introspection: use the legacy user-info endpoint to introspect opaque tokens.

That said, you have at least two options for configuring your resource servers:

- create a single security filter-chain with a custom authentication manager resolver deciding to use JWT decoder or introspection depending on the authorization header format
- create two separate security filter-chain with security matchers for each type of authorization (one for JWT access tokens and another one for legacy tokens to introspect)

In both cases, the configuration for the "legacy" tokens would be quite [standard configuration for resource server with introspection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html) (so called "opaque token" in Spring's doc, even if you can introspect JWTs), **with a custom introspector** submitting the token to the user-info endpoint you mention in your comments.

The `securityMatcher` in the second option are probably easier to write than the `AuthenticationManagerResolver` in the first. You could get inspirations from [this security matcher](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/ed1e8da796dafd667ae5f308d05d62726066449c/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/BasicAuthSecurityConfig.java#L77) (off course the condition won't be the same for you as you're probably matching a `bearer` pattern raser than `basic` string).

Comment: both scenarios handle only oauth flow but what about the non-oauth flow? . And can we have multiple fiter-chain configured one for oauth and other for non-oauth?

Comment: Yes, the second option is exactly that: one filter-chain per request authorization type. So far, I don't understand why you write that the legacy system is not OAuth. As far as I understand, requests are secured with opaque `Bearer` access tokens validated by an external server => from resource server point of view, this is plain OAuth2 introspection (how tokens are acquired is none of their business).

Comment: consider that for non-auth we get username and password from the user and using that we make an api call to the other server which understand the username and password and return us a base64 encoded string. to get the user details for authorization we send encoded string to the server but to other api endpoint which return a user object.

Comment: so how can i implement that using second option?